# How to update Excel Cell based on validation using ClosedXML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, closedxml

I have an input excel file which contains 6 columns and n number of rows. Out of which 3 columns are mandatory columns. If any of mandatory columns are empty then I need to update some custom text in the Remarks column. In the input excel column names are fixed but position is not fixed.

For example, in the below table I have updated Remarks column values of row no. 2 & 3 as Fail since CCode and ID column values are blank.

| Name | ID | ComapanyName | CCode | Address | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anto | 12 | ABC Corp Cmp | ABCCo | AvenueSt |  |
| Anuj | 13 | XYZ Corp Cmp |  | AvenueSt | Fail |
| Kathy |  | CTF Corp Cmp | CTFCo | AvenueSt | Fail |

**Close XML Logic:**

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook(IPPath);
    var rows     = workbook.Worksheet(1).RangeUsed().RowsUsed().Skip(1);

    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        -- update logic
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read the excel data in DataTable, then you should be able to update the excel data by iterating each record.

```
private static System.Data.DataTable ReadExcelData(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Data.DataTable dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
                using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(stream))
                    {

                        var workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
                        dataTable.TableName = workSheet.Name;

                        int lastRowIndex = workSheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
                        int lastColumnIndex = workSheet.LastColumnUsed().ColumnNumber();
                        bool header = false;

                        foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows(1, lastRowIndex))
                        {
                            if (!header)
                            {
                                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, lastColumnIndex))
                                {
                                    dataTable.Columns.Add(cell.GetFormattedString());
                                }
                                header = true;
                            }
                            dataTable.Rows.Add();
                            int i = 0;
                            foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells(1, lastColumnIndex))
                            {
                                dataTable.Rows[dataTable.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell.GetFormattedString();
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                        dataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }

                return dataTable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static void UpdateData(string filePath, DataTable dataTable)
        {
            using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (XLWorkbook workBook = new XLWorkbook(stream))
                {
                    var workSheet = workBook.Worksheet(1);
                    if (workSheet != null)
                    {
                        int ColumnIndex = 0;
                        int rowNumber = 1;
                        foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
                        {
                            if (column.ColumnName.Contains("Column Name"))
                            {
                                ColumnIndex = column.Ordinal + 1;
                            }
                        }
                        string colAddress = ColumnAddress(ColumnIndex);

                        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                        {
                            rowNumber++;
                            workSheet.Cell(rowNumber, ColumnIndex).Value = "Update Value";
                        }
                    }
                    workBook.Save();
                }
            }

        }

        private static string ColumnAddress(int col)
        {
            if (col <= 26)
            {
                return Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(col + 64));
            }
            int div = col / 26;
            int mod = col % 26;
            if (mod == 0) { mod = 26; div--; }
            return ColumnAddress(div) + ColumnAddress(mod);
        }
```